# Truffle compiling error

Tags: truffle

I having the error below when I tried compile the contract. Should I downgrade the truffle version? If yes, which version because I couldn't find the appropriate version for sol 0.4.18. Thanks

```
SyntaxError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compil
er is 0.4.24+commit.e67f0147.Emscripten.clang - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity 0.4.18;
^--------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, each Truffle version comes with a built-in solidity compiler. One possible solution is to downgrade to the version of Truffle that corresponds to solidity 0.4.18 which is the version the author is signaling he or she worked with.

It may be more forward-thinking to bump the contract source up to 0.4.24. This is going to cause some syntax-level compiler complaints. They're not alarming to people who have worked with it for a while but dialect differences could be a nuisance if you're looking for a smooth path.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Another option is to modify the source to allow compilation with newer versions `pragma solidity ^0.4.18` (the `^` in front allow compilation with newer compilers compatibles with 0.4.18 ie all from the 0.4.xx https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json).

Answer (score 0):

On mainnet or locally, for a specific smart contract and his parents, only one solidity version can be used.

For example, on Etherscan, you can check the Compiler Version of a smart contract.

Make sure you find a version that is supported by all your smart contracts. Then, change truffle-config.js to set the expected solc version.

```
module.exports = {
    networks: {
        development: {
            host: "127.0.0.1",
            port: 7545,
            network_id: "*" // Match any network id
        }
    },
    compilers: {
        solc: {
            version: "0.4.24" <--- This is what you need to change
        }
    }
 };
```

After changing that, make sure you installed this specific solc version on your computer.
To check all installed version you can run

```
truffle compile --list
```

And to install a new version you can run

```
npm install solc@[VERSION-YOU-WANT]
```